# Answer Facebook comments plugin using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use Facebook Comments Plugin in my page. Now, I want to answer this comment through my application. Can I make a graph api call to do that? When I make a POST request with the id and the text I get a OauthException.

Example call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/1037048532996150_1037052016329135?message=Hello
```

Result:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Permissions error",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "E8H8jVVVXGt"
  },
}
```

I haven't a facebook page, I have a html where I include a facebook comments plugin, putting a small script tag and a div in my code.

This is my HTML code

```
<body onload="loadFB();">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '635459129889611',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.4'
        });
      };
    </script>

    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=635459129889611";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://socialmediacrm.es/comments_fb.php" data-width="500" data-numposts="5"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to log in the Facebook user if that has not happened yet and you need to check the permissions you need to do that. If one or more permissions are needed, then you need to ask for it.

Comment: Hello Lajos, I push in get user access token, with an administrator of the application, check all the permissions, but still getting the oAuthError 

Regards

Comment: Can you share your code where you received the token and where you checked the permissions? What language are you using, what SDK?

Comment: I use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

I have included the plugin on my page. The problem is when I try to answer a comment_id through graph api, I think that is different than a normal comment in the wall

Comment: what CMS are you using? Wordpress?

Comment: Not, only a page test, just html code

Comment: Can you share the relevant part of your code?

Answer (score 0):

> Permissions
>
> ```
> A user access token with publish_action permission can be used to publish new comments on behalf of that user.
> A page access token with publish_pages permission can be used to publish new comments on behalf of that Page.
> The same user or Page must also be able to comment on the object.
> The can_comment field on individual comment objects indicates whether it is possible to reply to that comment by publishing another.
> ```

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/comments/).

As you can see, you need `publish_actions` privilege to comment on behalf of a user.

> When to ask for Permissions
>
> Your app can ask for additional permissions at any time, even after a
>   person logs in for the first time. For example, the publish_actions
>   permission lets you post to a person's Facebook Timeline. It's
>   recommended you ask for this permission only when a person is ready to
>   publish a story to Facebook. When you ask for new permissions, the
>   person using your app will be asked about those new permissions and
>   has the ability to opt out. We cover optimizing permissions requests
>   later in this document.
>
> Permissions only need to be granted once per app, i.e. permissions
>   granted on one platform are effectively granted on all the platforms
>   your app supports.

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5).

This is how you can post a comment from PHP:

```
/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'POST',
  '/{object-id}/comments',
  array (
    'message' => 'This is a test comment',
  )
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/comments#publish).